# Windows 11 laptop fails to wake properly from sleep, then prompts for BitLocker recovery key after first reboot

Tags: boot, windows-11, sleep, bitlocker

We're having trouble with an LG gram 17" Model 17Z90Q laptop.  Occasionally it will wake from sleep to only a a black screen with only the mouse cursor, requiring a reboot.  It will then prompt for the BitLocker recovery key after the first reboot, but will not ask for it after a second reboot (without the key ever being provided).

1. What could be causing the wakes to a black screen with only the mouse cursor? How can I prevent those?
2. What could be causing the single BitLocker recovery prompt?  How could I prevent those from happening at all?

---

Here's the precise sequence of events:

1. Put laptop to sleep by closing lid.
2. Open laptop, it stays asleep with the light next to the power button flashing slowly.
3. **Short-press power button to turn on. Laptop goes through BIOS splash screen, and gets stuck at a black screen with mouse cursor.**
4. After waiting 5 minutes, long-press power button to shutdown.
5. Short-press power button to turn on.
6. **Laptop boots into BitLocker recovery.**
7. Long-press power button to shutdown, then short-press power button to turn on.
8. **Laptop boots into Windows normally.**

Comment: (1) Test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html), (2) Run [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) for many hours over-night, (3) Verify the SMART attributes of the disk. Use [speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy) if you don't have such a tool, as it will mark attributes as Good or not.

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution? Got the same problem...